# How to change D3.js graph from SVG to canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, svg

I have a D3.js graph drawn as an SVG. Now, I want to print the graph as an image. Taking a screenshot of the page hasn't worked because the output is the graph's background image. So now I want to try drawing the graph as a canvas. I tried changing the following:

```
d3.select("svg")
```

to

```
d3.select("canvas")
```

but the graph doesn't appear. A full link to the code is below. What else do I need to change?

http://scrs-test.comli.com/results-demo.php

Comment: You'd have to convert all the SVG DOM manipulation to the equivalent canvas methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [SVG Crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) developed by the New York Times to extract an SVG image, then import that image to Illustrator or Inkscape to rasterize to an image.

Your link to "code" asks me to log-in.  :)